# Java8 : リストをラムダ式で処理する時の `while...continue` と同等のループ制御

Tags: java, java8, lambda

リストを`forEach()`メソッドでラムダ式によって処理している際、`for`、`while`で使われる`continue`と同じ動作を行う方法を共有します。

```java
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd");

list.stream().forEach(str -> {
    if (str.equals("ccc")) {
        // 次の要素に行きたい(continueしたい)
    }
    System.out.println(str);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ラムダ式の場合、`return`を行うことでラムダブロックを抜け、次の要素の処理に移行します。

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd");

list.stream().forEach(str -> {
    if (str.equals("ccc")) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(str);
});
```

**実行結果**

```
aaa
bbb
ddd
```